Transaction failure without any reason
Guys its very irritating, my transaction is failing for like 3 days.
3 days ago I wanted to send some sol to other wallet, I had $0.1 of sol in it and wanted to send a little ammount, but the fees was showing 0.00002sol still it was failing(2 times), when I tried in trust wallet it was showing not enough sol.
Then I had one token in my wallet which I wanted to send to other wallet, for 2 days I was trying to send it but transaction was failing, today, I had like $0.3 of sol and still it was failing, in bitget wallet it was showing this error- Your SOL balance is below the minimum required for rent exemption. Top up your SOL balance and try again. Why is it happening? means fees is $0.001 but still its showing not enough balance.
My address to check what wrong was happening- 77otVFwmJcnZC78yM3hVjeU8DMz8J4wWRBDM1PYKWjbQ
Thanks

there could be 2 reasons:
an account to "stay alive" in the blockchain has to have a minimum SOL balance (the rent). Either after your transaction your account doesn't have enough sol to get this minmum, either you are sending SOL to a new wallet (with 0 sol inside), and then you also have to provide the rent in order to "create" this account on the blockchain

so means the sending wallet should have some sol and the recieving too? Bro I sent 1 token to the new account (with 0sol), and had to pay 0.002sol, so now if I send that same token again then I only have pay gas which is 0.00002sol?

yes the first time you send a token to a wallet, if this wallet never had this token, a token account is created, and you have to pay for the rent of this token account (approx 0.002 sol). Next time you send the same token to the same address, you don't have to fund that anymore, you pay only the tx fees. And FYI, you can redeem the 0.002 SOL if you close the token account (meaning you don't have tokens anymore or you accept to lose them)
